# openxlsx not able to read from .xlsx file in R

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, xlconnect

I am trying to read value from a `.xlsx` file using `openxlsx` package in `R`. In simple words,  I need to write a row of data, which then populates some output cell that has to be read back in R. I will share an example to better explain the problem.

Initial state of the `.xlsx` file:

[image]

I'm now trying to write new values to the cell : A2:A3 = c("c", 5). So ideally, I'm expecting `A6 = 15`

Below is the code used :

```
require(openxlsx)
path <- "C:/path_to_file/for_SO1.xlsx"
input_row <- c("c", 5)
# Load workbook; create if not existing
wb <- loadWorkbook(path)
# createSheet(wb, name = "1")
writeData(wb, 
          sheet = "Sheet1",
          x = data.frame(input_row),
          startCol=1,
          startRow=1
)  

data_IM <- read.xlsx(wb, 
                     sheet = "Sheet1",
                     rows = c(5,6),
                     cols = c(1))
# Save workbook
saveWorkbook(wb, file = path, overwrite = TRUE)

#> data_IM
#  output_row
#1          3
```

But I get the inital value(3). However, If i open the `.xlsx` file, I can see the `15` residing there:

[image]

What could be the reason for not able to read this cell? I tried saving it after writing to the file and again reading it but even that failed. `openxlsx` is the only option I have due to JAVA errors from XLConnect etc.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer thankyou for informing.. I am not getting nay replies and I'm still stuck here

Comment: Might be worth adding the Java errors you have mentioned. Also, tomorrow you can add a bounty to the question, to tempt people into answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
?read.xlsx
```

> Formulae written using writeFormula to a Workbook object will not get
>   picked up by read.xlsx(). This is because only the formula is written
>   and left to be evaluated when the file is opened in Excel. Opening,
>   saving and closing the file with Excel will resolve this.

So the file needs to be opened in Excel and then saved, I can verify that this does work. However this may not be suitable for you.

`XLConnect` seems to have the desired functionality

```
# rjava can run out of memory sometimes, this can help.
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1G")
library(XLConnect)

file_path = "test.xlsx"

input_row <- c("c", 5)

wb <- loadWorkbook(file_path, create=F)
writeWorksheet(wb, 1, startRow = 1, startCol = 1, data = data.frame(input_row))
setForceFormulaRecalculation(wb, 1, TRUE)
saveWorkbook(wb)

# checking
wb <- loadWorkbook(file_path, create=F)
readWorksheet(wb, 1)
```

Comment: XLConnect can dynamically evaluate the formula and does give me the naswer but the issue with it is it doesn't support TRANSPOSE from excel and some other functions(being used in my calculations). It keeps giving me Apache POI Array error.

Comment: So use openxlsx, save it, read it in with XLConnect, recalc, then save? I've otherwise 100% addressed the question.

Comment: though I am still stuck, it's my duty to tickmark this! thank you

Answer (score 0):

The file https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/openxlsx.pdf says

Workbook object will not get picked up by read.xlsx().
This is because only the formula is written and left to be evaluated when the file is opened in Excel.
Opening, saving and closing the file with Excel will resolve this.
So if you are using windows then
save following file vbs file to for example opensaveexcel.vbs

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Book2.xlsx")
objWorkbook.Save
objWorkbook.Close 
objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
```

and then you can write R code as cell A4 has formula in Book1.xlsx as =A3*5

```
mywritexlsx(fname="d:/Book1.xlsx",data = 20,startCol = 1,startRow = 3)
system("cp d:\\Book1.xlsx d:\\Book2.xlsx")
system("cscript //nologo d:\\opensaveexcel.vbs")
tdt1=read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "d:/Book1.xlsx",sheet = "Sheet1",colNames = FALSE)
tdt2=read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "d:/Book2.xlsx",sheet = "Sheet1",colNames = FALSE)
```

Works for me by the way mywritexlsx is as

```
mywritexlsx<-function(fname="temp.xlsx",sheetname="Sheet1",data,
                  startCol = 1, startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE, rowNames = FALSE)
{
  if(!file.exists(fname))
  {
   wb = openxlsx::createWorkbook()
   sheet = openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb, sheetname)
  }
  else
 {
   wb <- openxlsx::loadWorkbook(file =fname)
   if(!(sum(openxlsx::getSheetNames(fname)==sheetname)))
   sheet = openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb, sheetname)
   else
    sheet=sheetname
  }

  openxlsx::writeData(wb,sheet,data,startCol = startCol, startRow = startRow, 
          colNames = colNames, rowNames = rowNames)
  openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, fname,overwrite = TRUE)
}
```