# Excel formula not updating after writing new data through R openxlsx package

Tags: r, excel, excel-2010, openxlsx

I'm trying to automate some processes in **Excel** using **R language** and **openxlsx** library.

When I write new data to a cell (which works fine) that is a reference to a formula in other cells, those cells with formulas do not update their values, even after I save the file and try to read it again.

Is there any workaround to fix this behavior?

Code and workbook follow.

```
library(openxlsx)

getwd()
setwd('Downloads')

wb = loadWorkbook('Plan.xlsx')
wb

activeSheet(wb) = 2
activeSheet(wb)

writeData(wb, sheet=2, startCol = 2, startRow = 2, x = 'p2')
print(read.xlsx(wb, sheet=2, startRow = 2, cols = c(3,4,5), colNames = F))
saveWorkbook(wb, file = 'Plan.xlsx', overwrite = T, returnValue = T)
```

[Plan1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0xim.png)
[Plan2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPRob.png)

Tried to:

1. save the file;
2. close it;
3. read it again;

expecting to have the cells updated with their new values.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "read it again".  If you mean read in R without opening Excel, I doubt it's possible, as Excel would need do the recalculation.  If you mean open in Excel, I'd see if `openxlsx` has the equivalent of `XLConnect::setForceFormulaRecalculation()`, which I've used successfully - it recalculates all formulas on opening in Excel.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/46914303/1714 seems to cover the same problem, and has some `XLConnect` code - not sure if it's any help.

Comment: If you want an automated Excel process then use Excel's VBA to it. If you want to automate in R then don't count on Excel.

Comment: @Hobo, thanks for pointing me that. I had to use `XLConnect`, as `openxlsx` doesn't have a similar function. By 'read it again' I first meant to read it in R, but doing some research, I saw that's not a trivial problem. Despite, `XLConnect` worked fine and for now should be enough.

Comment: @Dave2e, as I don't have experience with VBA, I tried to use R, and for some tasks it performed as expected.