# read.xlsx/read_excel not refreshing formulas

Tags: r, rscript

I am trying to read in some cells with formulas into R, however, when I try to do this it does not update the formulas so it is not being read in correctly. So far I have tried:

1. read_excel(path, sheet = "Results Summary", col_types = "text")
2. data.frame(read.xlsx(xlsxFile = path, sheet = "Results Summary", startRow = 2, colNames = FALSE))

Is there anyway I can solve this? I noticed that if I open the workbook manually and calculate the workbook and save it then the above formulas work properly in terms of reading the data.

Are there any alternatives that anyone can recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: See here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014692/read-excel-file-with-formulas-in-cells-into-r>. Otherwise please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The term ‘formula’ has a specific meaning in the R language language. It does not appear that you are askin about R formulae. What you typed might be called commands but they are not formula.